# Hide arguments in Visio UML sequence diagram

Tags: uml, visio, sequence-diagram

Is it possible to hide the arguments list in a Visio UML sequence diagram?
Currently, when I add a message call to the diagram it appears like this:

```
operationName( param1, param2)
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
operationName()
```

I am wondering if it is doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that what you want is to see the operation like this: "operationName()".

I don't have a good solution (dunno if there is a configuration property that allows to hide the arguments in Visio) but two possible workarounds:

- param1 and param2 are the arguments of the operation in the call, you can delete the name (i.e. define the argument name as the empty string)
  and then you would see the operation like this "operationName(,)"
- You can directly give the name "operationName()" to the message call (without relating the call with the operation in the class. However, be careful with this solution, because then if you change the name of the operation in the class diagram, the name of the message in the sequence diagram won't be updated